# Allow two attempts at an answer for a JS quiz

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a way in which to allow someone to have two attempts at a question in a JS quiz, and found this old thread: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?271527-Help-a-newbie-with-short-quiz which was posted over a year ago, with it ending with the issue that the user that two "lives" overall rather than two attempts at a question, and no response. The code is below:

```
var total = 3; 
var score = 0; 
var correct = 1; 

//array list with questions & answers 
var questions = [ 
    ['What is the capital of England?', 'London'],   
    ['What is the capital of Scotland?', 'Edinburgh'], 
    ['What do you call a baby cat?', 'Kitten'] 
]; 

function askQuestion(question) //calling the function 

{ 
    var answer = prompt(question[0], ""); //using prompt to pull question from array and assing users answer to var 
        if (answer == question[1]) //if statement checking if answer = answer pulled from array list 
        { 
            alert("Correct! " + "You have scored " + correct + " out of " + total);
            score++; 
            correct++ 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert("Sorry. The correct answer is " + question[1]); 
        } 
} 

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) // counter which will end loop after 3 questions answered.  

{ 
    askQuestion(questions[i]); // indexing the array for the next question to be pulled 
} 

document.writeln("Well done! Your final score is " + score + " out of " + total);
```

So rather than posting on a dead thread, I'm hoping that one of you can help me out- should be an easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: You know that, if you make a JS quiz, just looking at the source of the page will get you the answers, right?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - Yes, but that's no fun is it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fix,

```
var total = 3; 
var score = 0; 
var correct = 1; 

//array list with questions & answers 
var questions = [ 
    ['What is the capital of England?', 'London'],   
    ['What is the capital of Scotland?', 'Edinburgh'], 
    ['What do you call a baby cat?', 'Kitten'] 
]; 

var attempts=1;

function askQuestion(question,x) //calling the function 

{ 
    var answer = prompt(question[0], ""); //using prompt to pull question from array and assing users answer to var 
        if (answer == question[1]) //if statement checking if answer = answer pulled from array list 
        { 
            alert("Correct! " + "You have scored " + correct + " out of " + total+" ");
            score++; 
            correct++;

        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert("Sorry. The correct answer is " + question[1]); 
            attempts--;
            if(attempts>=0){
                askQuestion(questions[x],x);
            }

        } 
} 

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) // counter which will end loop after 3 questions answered.  

{ 
    askQuestion(questions[i],i);
    attempts=1; // indexing the array for the next question to be pulled 
} 

document.writeln("Well done! Your final score is " + score + " out of " + total);
```